# Is there any way to use separate alignment for title key and data elements in a table?

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, struts, styling

```
<display:column property="Id" style="width:8%;text-align: left" titleKey="ordercount"></display:column>
```

in the above code ,both the title and data element are aligned left. Is there any way I can make header aligned at center and data elements aligned left.